# Approximate Equivalent To Michael Spivak's text, "Calculus" but for Linear Algebra?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, reference-request

Does anyone know of an approximate equivalent To Michael Spivak's text, "Calculus" but for Linear Algebra? I love the way this book is written! It is simultaneously rigorous and thorough without antagonizing or belittling the clouded reader seeking clarity. I just started going through the text and love how I have not yet ran across the word "clearly" kicking of a paragraph. If I answer a question with clearly such and such on a test clearly I will fail and so will an author in bringing a larger audience to understanding quickly.

Comment: Sheldon Axler - Linear Algebra Done Right.

Comment: Many people (besides myself) like Gilbert Strang's _Linear Algebra and its Applications_ , currently in its fourth edition.

Answer (score 2):

I love Calculus by Spivak!

For Linear Algebra, I would recommend the text by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence.  I thought it was very well written, and very enlightening.

The text by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence provides a somewhat abstract view of linear algebra.  Vector spaces are not restricted to subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  If you're only interested in dealing with $\mathbb{R}^n$ then the simpler book "Linear Algebra with Applications" by Bretscher is a very good text.

Comment: I just went through Frieberg et al. up to inner product spaces over a six week summer course. The book is so frustrating when your under pressure. Maybe six weeks was a little too short for this course I never felt good going into our tests and did average in the class which wasn't so bad. I don't know linear algebra pedology can get me into conspiracy theory land.

Comment: Hmmmm...  Perhaps you went through the material too quickly.  Linear Algebra is surprisingly easy; the only thing that makes it difficult is that there's so much of it!  I had the benefit of first reviewing the text by Bretscher before studying the book by Fridberg et al.  Perhaps that'd be a good place to start?

Comment: Friedberg, Insel, and Spence wrote two very different textbooks on linear algebra, both in common use: see http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Edition-Stephen-Friedberg/dp/0130084514 and http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Linear-Algebra-Lawrence-Spence/dp/0131871412/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1407906939&sr=1-2. You should probably specify which one.

Comment: It was "Linear Algebra." Also it was a proof based class at very competitive university. The answers to certain test questions would leave you smacking yourself in the head later on when you realized how simple the problem was. Half of each exam was unseen problems unless you spent half a year or more studying before the class. Blah, I'm just whining I'm more of a biologist/chemist than a mathematician. Give me Ochem problems and I'll fly through them with normal study. But I do love math nevertheless.

Comment: @kiegen; I was referring to Linear Algebra.